# How in perforce p4v can I delete all cloned local files and folder from selected workspace that are not in any changelist?

Tags: perforce, p4v

How can I in perforce p4v can I delete all those local those files and folder from selected workspace that are not in any `changelist` ?

currently I have almost all the depot copied on my machine with only few of the changelists, I think I can free up space if I delete the files that are not in any of the changelist of selected workspace.

Comment: Your client view is probably too wide, with too many wildcards, and is causing you to sync too many branches. Refine your client view to be more selective, and re-sync.

Comment: what `client view` are you referring to?

Comment: https://www.perforce.com/perforce/r13.1/manuals/p4v/Defining_a_client_view.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question as phrased doesn't make sense, because every file in your workspace that you synced from the depot, and every file in your depot that you cloned from a remote server, is part of at least one submitted changelist.

If you want to remove all the files from your workspace that are not **open in a pending changelist**, that's a simple "remove from workspace" operation at the workspace root (or just `p4 sync #none` at the command line).  The `sync` command will automatically skip files that are open, because it doesn't want to delete your work in progress.

To delete files in your workspace that did not come from the depot (i.e. files that are truly not part of any changelist, either pending or submitted), use the `p4 clean` command.  This will irrevocably delete these files and there will be no way to get them back (since they were never submitted to the depot for safekeeping), so make sure this is really what you want to do!